# From ....... on/onwards, after

Tags: word-usage

I was telling someone that "platyhelminthes" is the last phylum which shows organ (and the only phylum) level of organization and after that all other phylas show "organ system level of organization". Now how's this  question related to English? Well, I want to know how I can naturally express it.

> **After** platyhelminthes all the phylas show organ system level of organization.
>
> **From** aschelminthes **on** all the phylas show organ system level of organization. (Aschelminthes too shows organ system level of organization)

So what would sound natural "after" or "from......on"? What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

> "...level of organization, **thereafter** all other phylas show..."

[Here's](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99971/usage-of-after-that) another thread about the usage of "after that".

Comment: And what about my options? Are they both unnatural?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Idk "after that" is pretty okay. I'm not a native either.

Comment: Maybe "after" can sound a bit informal and "thereafter" maybe something that one will find in biology books..

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish You're right, but to me "therefore" sounds more natural here.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish You've read [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99971/usage-of-after-that)?

Comment: So it does sound natural, but "thereafter" , "after which" are favored in more formal contexts. Thank you for finding this already existing thread (+1)

Comment: And maybe you can add this information to your answer, it'll make it better and  more suitable for this site :)

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish okay